# Changing a value from another field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change a value that was set from javascript(jQuery) from another field. I want to target only one word from that value. Here's my code (http://jsfiddle.net/zL4pc90d/):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>jQuery get input Text value example</title>
  <script
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#select_car").change(function()
      {
        if ($("#select_car").val() == "")
        {
          terms = "";
        } else if ($("#select_car").val() == "Honda")
        {
          terms = "One year lease on <car>.";
        } else if ($("#select_car").val() == "Toyota")
        {
          terms  = "Two year lease on <car>.";
        } else if ($("#select_car").val() == "Ford")
        {
          terms = "Three year lease on <car>.";
        }
        $("#contract").val(terms);
      });
    }); 
  </script>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>jQuery Get and Set input Text value</legend>
        <p>
          <label for="carModel">
            Car Model:
          </label>
          <input id="myInputText" type="text" name="inputBox" />
        </p>
        <p>
          Make:
          <select id="select_car">
            <option value></option>
            <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
            <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
            <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
          </select>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="contract">
            Contract:
          </label>
          <input id="contract" type="text" name="outputBox" readonly="readonly" />
        </p>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For the new values, wherever it says "", I'd like it to be what I enter in the first input field. I'd prefer to do it dynamically too, so maybe calling the keyup function or something. How would I do this?

Comment: Am I right that you would like to join text of car model to car type got from option of select menu?

Comment: is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/zL4pc90d/2/ ?

Comment: @Runcorn Nope. What I want is that when I'm typing the "Car Model" in, it'll change the "<car>" text in the Contract field. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input` event to track what the user inputs in your input field and update value accordingly to the other box,

```
 $("#myInputText").on("input", function () {
        if ($("#myInputText").val() != "") {
            terms = "Three year lease on " + $("#myInputText").val();
        } else terms = terms = "Three year lease on <car>";

        $("#contract").val(terms);
    });
```

#### See a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zL4pc90d/3/)

Comment: Almost. How do I make it so when I'm entering in the field, it dynamically updates the text? Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/zL4pc90d/4/